# Using Sliders in Maya with Python to control Shapes - intSliderGrp

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to use the following sliders for the Colour, Translate, Rotate and Scale for the shapes I have in this code. Is there a way I can control all the shapes with these sliders? I can't seem to figure it out I've tried everything that I could. I would like to do this with maybe a function but any solution is helpful Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
    #Importing all Maya commands to Python
import maya.cmds as cmds
from functools import partial

class CreateUI():
    def __init__(self):
        windowID = "myWindowID"

        if cmds.window(windowID, exists=True):
            cmds.deleteUI(windowID)

#-----------------------------------------------Layout of Interface 

        masterWindow = cmds.window(windowID, title="User Interface", w=500, h=800, sizeable=False, resizeToFitChildren=True)
        ShapeLayout = cmds.rowColumnLayout(parent=masterWindow, numberOfColumns=1, columnOffset=[(2,"left",0)])



#-----------------------------------------------Shape Functions       

#Functions for creating shapes        
        def mySphere(*args):
            cmds.polySphere()

        def myCube(*args):
            cmds.polyCube()

        def myCylinder(*args):
            cmds.polyCylinder()

        def myCone(*args):
            cmds.polyCone()

        def myTorus(*args):
            cmds.polyTorus()

        def myPlane(*args):
            cmds.polyPlane()

        def myDelete(*args):
            cmds.select()
            cmds.delete()

#Gets rid of any shapes in the scene so that the user doesn't have to every time the UI is launched or the sript is run
        ShapeList = cmds.ls("mySphere*", "myCube*", "myCylinder*", "myCone*", "myTorus*", "myPlane*","pSphere*", "pCube*", "pCylinder*", "pCone*", "pTorus*", "pPlane*")
        if len(ShapeList)>0:
            cmds.delete(ShapeList)

#-----------------------------------------------Shape Buttons         

#Buttons for creating shapes    
        cmds.button(label="Sphere", command=mySphere)
        cmds.button(label="Cube", command=myCube)
        cmds.button(label="Cylinder", command=myCylinder)
        cmds.button(label="Cone", command=myCone)
        cmds.button(label="Torus", command=myTorus)
        cmds.button(label="Plane", command=myPlane)
        cmds.button(label="Delete", command=myDelete)

        #COLOUR
        cmds.separator(h=20, style="none")
        cmds.colorSliderGrp('blockColour',label="Colour", hsv=(120, 1, 1))
        cmds.separator(h=20, style="none")

        #TRANSLATE
        TranslateX = cmds.intSliderGrp('TX',label="Translate X ", field=True, min=1, max=100, value=0)  
        TranslateY = cmds.intSliderGrp('TY',label="Translate Y ", field=True, min=1, max=100, value=0)
        TranslateZ = cmds.intSliderGrp('TZ',label="Translate Z ", field=True, min=1, max=100, value=0)
        cmds.separator(h=20, style="none")

        #ROTATE
        RotateX = cmds.intSliderGrp('RX',label="Rotate X ", field=True, min=1, max=100, value=0)  
        RotateY = cmds.intSliderGrp('RY',label="Rotate Y ", field=True, min=1, max=100, value=0)
        RotateZ = cmds.intSliderGrp('RZ',label="Rotate Z ", field=True, min=1, max=100, value=0)
        cmds.separator(h=20, style="none")

        #SCALE
        ScaleX = cmds.intSliderGrp('SX',label="Scale X ", field=True, min=1, max=100, value=0)  
        ScaleY = cmds.intSliderGrp('SY',label="Scale Y ", field=True, min=1, max=100, value=0)
        ScaleZ = cmds.intSliderGrp('SZ',label="Scale Z ", field=True, min=1, max=100, value=0)




        cmds.showWindow(windowID)
ui=CreateUI()
```

Comment: This looks exactly the same as your other question: [Using Sliders for shapes in Maya with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50110785/2745495). Please refrain from posting duplicate questions.

Comment: Sorry it's because I didn't receive an answer, it was late night so I thought not many people would see it

Comment: Do you know the solution to the above problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Sliders for shapes in Maya with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110785/using-sliders-for-shapes-in-maya-with-python)

Comment: Yeah i know how to solve above problem. But it is really not a problem you want to solve the way you describe. See your thinking "Python code to drive them all". But you shouldn't do that you should "think **nodes** to drive them all" Then suddenly you dont even have to build the sliders as maya does it for you.

Comment: my advise would be : don't use class at the moment. It seems you are beginning python and you should focus on the basics. in your code you are missing ie : return statement, partial, list appending, slider signal and slot.

Comment: What have you tried so far to control them through the sliders? You'll get more responses if you show what you have attempted so far. (the current code is just defining the interface, not any attempt on using the sliders at all)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know more about sliders and various ui :

[How to store the value of floatSliderGrp in Python Maya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43569064/how-to-store-the-value-of-floatslidergrp-in-python-maya/43571312#43571312)

[How to create Maya sliders to move objects in interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255426/how-to-create-maya-sliders-to-move-objects-in-interface/43256245#43256245)

[Material and Texture Change Python Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49539265/material-and-texture-change-python-script/49541788#49541788)

[Maya 2015 Python - textField input, radioButton selection not working in UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41742822/maya-2015-python-textfield-input-radiobutton-selection-not-working-in-ui/41743800#41743800)

UI in maya is the most ask question, check topics I've answered
You can check also Theodox answers : https://stackoverflow.com/users/1936075/theodox

Answer (score 0):

For the very specific application you seem to be trying here, you can also short-circuit some of the work using the [attrFieldSliderGrp](https://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/show.html?attrFieldSliderGrp.html&cat=Windows) control which is precisely for passing numbers directly from a gui to an object attribute.

To make this work you'll need to make sure that when you want to edit an object, all of the sliders will need to know it's name.  The lazy method would be to make sure that the function just works on the selected item -- though that's not likely to be what you want.

Passing information between the buttons is a bit tricky (for reasons detailed [here](https://theodox.github.io/2014/maya_callbacks_cheat_sheet).  Basically you'll need to make sure that the controls all know which object is being worked on and do their work on it. Although in general a class is overkill for simple GUI in this case the class provides an pretty simple way to handle this.

Here's a cut-down example of how it can be done:

```
        import maya.cmds as cmds

        class ShapeUI(object):   # remember to inherit from object in python 2 classes!
            WINDOW_NAME = "myWindowID"   # put this up here so all copies of this class share it

            def __init__(self):


                # you need to remember the name of the object you want to work on
                self.active_shape = None
                self.layout()

            def layout(self):

                if cmds.window(self.WINDOW_NAME, exists=True):
                    cmds.deleteUI(self.WINDOW_NAME)
                cmds.window(self.WINDOW_NAME, title="User Interface", resizeToFitChildren=True)
                cmds.columnLayout(adjustableColumn=True)

                cmds.button(label="Sphere", command=self.mySphere)
                cmds.button(label="Cube", command=self.myCube)
                cmds.button(label = 'delete active', command = self.myDelete)
                cmds.separator(h=20, style="none")

                # you need to remember the ids of the sliders so you can query their values
                self.TranslateX = cmds.intSliderGrp(
                    label="Translate X ", field=True, min=1, max=100, value=0, cc=self.move_active)
                self.TranslateY = cmds.intSliderGrp(
                    label="Translate Y ", field=True, min=1, max=100, value=0, cc=self.move_active)
                self.TranslateZ = cmds.intSliderGrp(
                    label="Translate Z ", field=True, min=1, max=100, value=0, cc=self.move_active)

                cmds.showWindow(self.WINDOW_NAME)

            def mySphere(self, *_):  # _ is python slang for "I will ignore this argument"
                self.active_shape = cmds.polySphere()[0]
                # for good measure, change the window title to the name of the active object
                cmds.window(self.WINDOW_NAME, e=true, title = self.active_shape)

            def myCube(self, *_):
                self.active_shape = cmds.polyCube()[0]
                cmds.window(self.WINDOW_NAME, e=true, title = self.active_shape)

            def myDelete(self, *_):
                if self.active_shape:
                    cmds.delete(self.active_shape)
                    self.active_shape = None
                    cmds.window(self.WINDOW_NAME, e=true, title = "nothing selected")

            def move_active(self, *_):
                # you could do separate functions for each slider,
                # but in this case it's easler to do the same one everwhere
                # using the stored widget names and the stored shape
                if self.active_shape:
                    tx = cmds.intSliderGrp(self.TranslateX, q=True, v=True)
                    ty = cmds.intSliderGrp(self.TranslateY, q=True, v=True)
                    tz = cmds.intSliderGrp(self.TranslateZ, q=True, v=True)

                    cmds.xform(self.active_shape, t=(tx, ty, tz))
                else:
                    print "create a shape before adjusting sliders"


        ui=ShapeUI()
```

the basic trick is that all the functions use `self` so they have access to the variables `self.active_shape` , `self.TranslateX` and so on.